# Calculating columns and showing in a view

Tags: 2013, list-view

All,

I have a very large list (3000+ items). I need to show a view of this data. I need to show a count of every row (3 rows) of all the YES drop downs. The drop down rows may contain YES or NO. So I need a count of all the YES. I do not want to see the data in the view. I just want to see the count only. Any ideas ?

I just need a list or a view, that shows the three rows (A,B,C (which are YES/NO Columns). With each row showing the count of the YES's . but no data.. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: With or without code?

Comment: You can get this done via JSLink. Attach a javascript file to your view and do the calculation. A similar question was asked before here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/129727/js-link-group-count-list-sharepoint-2013

Comment: without code please. OOTB only

Comment: Does this need to be in the view with the data, or can it be in a separate KPI list?

Comment: Hi @Jammin4CO yes it can be an seperate list. I need the ammount of YES on three different rows and it needs to be displayed horizontally. The original list can be left as is.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to show a count of every row (3 rows) of all the YES drop downs.

You mean 3 columns/fields in **one** item ??

Since a True/Yes value equals 1 and False 0

You can use the SUM() function (*up to 30 parameters*)

```
=SUM( [Field1] ,  [Field2] ,  [Field3]  )
```

#### Update #1

OP wants the sum of a **column** and **not display the column in the view**

That is not possible out-of-the-box, can only be done with code

Comment: yes each row has 3 YES/NO columns. I want to count the YES's on each column, but I dont want to see any results - i just want to see the COUNT. OOTB only if you have any ideas.

Comment: If you don't want the "results" (by which I assume you mean the yes/no columns), simply don't include them in your view.

Comment: if i dont incluse them in my view, i dont get the count. I need the count. In the view you can add the count - thats all i need to see.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the closest I can get for you.

1. Make a view that has the columns you want to count.
2. In that view, in the Totals section add count totals.
3. In the Item Limit section, make batches of 1

This should get you in the right direction.  You may have to have a separate view with filters for each column to get accurate totals.  I also noticed in my testing that if you use the Yes/No column, the total only returns a count of "Yes".